# Ajax call taking me to another view instead of appending data to existing view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, append

I am attempting to update part of my page with a partial view similar to [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).  I can remove the partial view by clicking "delete" - so my jquery is working there, however I cannot add another line of the partial view.  When I click the link to 'add another row,' I get taken to a page that displays just the returned html instead of having that data appended to my current view.

Here is my main View:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ApplicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ApplyToSomething";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyJqueryAjaxFile.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Apply To Something</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EducationalBackground)
        </div>

        //
        // THIS IS THE SECTION I AM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH
        <div id = "editorRows">
            @Html.Partial("_EducationalBackground")
            <!-- PUT ADDITIONAL PARTIAL VIEWS HERE -->
        </div>

        @Html.ActionLink("Add another row", "EducationalBackground", null, new {id = "addItem"})

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WillingToTravel)
        </div>
        <div clsas="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WillingToTravel)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WillingToTravel)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is my Partial View:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ApplicationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editorRow">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UniversityOrCollege)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UniversityOrCollege)
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    </p>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my .js file:

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
});

$("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
    $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Here are my Controller Actions:

```
public ActionResult Apply()
{
    // I generate data for model. . .
    return View(model);
}

public PartialViewResult EducationalBackground()
{
    return PartialView("_EducationalBackground", new ApplicationViewModel());
}
```

And here is the exact copy/paste of the ViewSource of the view's Html (note that it lists actual values instead of things like "MyApp"):

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="EducationalBackground">EducationalBackground</label>
        </div>
        <div id = "editorRows">
            <h2>_EducationalBackground</h2>
<form action="/InstructorApplication/ApplyToBecomeInstructor" method="post">    <div class="editorRow">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="UniversityOrCollege" name="UniversityOrCollege" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UniversityOrCollege" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <p>
        <!--<a href="/InstructorApplication/%23?class=deleteRow">deleteRow</a>-->
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</form>
            <!-- PUT PARTIAL VIEWS HERE -->
        </div>

        <a href="/InstructorApplication/EducationalBackground" id="addItem">Add another row</a>
```

Why is my link to "Add another row" taking me to another view instead of appending the data to my current view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { $("#editorRows").append(data);  return false;}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your code and it still has the same behavior.  Hmm . . .  I made sure to refresh my browser's cache and try another browser as well - no luck.

Comment: hmmm try now. I think `success:` should I also return false

Comment: It is still taking me to another page.  Maybe the ajax call isn't being reached at all?  (although, by looking at the html it looks like it should work - to me at least)

Comment: That was it, thank you very much.  I did not think of doing so because I had just written another .js file (so I had just written a .ready funciton).

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the event to the callback function and try doing `event.preventDefault()` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
$("#addItem").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { $("#editorRows").append(data);}
    });
});
```

This will prevent the default event.